# Le puedo poner un scroll view a mi BottomNavView?

Tags: java, android

Hay alguna forma de ponerle un scrollview a mi BottomNavView? Sé que el BottomNavView puede tener como mucho 5 items. Necesito que tenga más... No sé si hay alguna forma de ponerle un horizontal scroll view para meterle más items... Si es que no, qué opciones tengo si tengo 6 o 7 items que necesito ponerle.

Obviamente quiero que el UI se vea bonito así que no quiero tener allí 7 items apretados y no muy atractivo visualmente.

Qué recomendaciones tenéis?

Comment: Es importante agregar como se muestra y que estas realizando, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Hola Jhon como bien dices el máximo "permitido" son 5, lo más parecido que he visto es este tutorial [https://www.raywenderlich.com/4638393-gesture-navigation-tutorial-for-android](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4638393-gesture-navigation-tutorial-for-android) Me parece una solución elegante a lo que pides, un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya te comenta en su respuesta [Alejandro Reyna](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/336513/161894), no se recomienda utilizar el [BottomNavigationView](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/) con más de 5 elementos dentro, y cito :

> No utilices más de 5 destinos. Para esos casos intenta con tabs o un navigation drawer.

Esta información la puedes encontrar [acá](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/#usage), actualmente hay un [feature request](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/543) en github en dónde un usuario está solicitando que se puedan agregar más de 5 elementos, aunque he visto que otros intentos han sido rechazados.

Pero, ¿que te parece si implementamos la alternativa que el propio google nos menciona en su guía?, a continuación te muestro una captura de un ejemplo que hice con [TabLayout](https://material.io/develop/android/components/tab-layout/) y [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código lo puedes descargar [acá](https://github.com/limpmike/BottomTabLayout).

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, espero que aprueben la solicitud de ponerle más items de alguna forma sin que se estropee el UI, mientras tanto utilizaré la TabLayout opción. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación oficial lo recomendable es tener hasta 4 items, MÁXIMO 5.

Si necesitas tener más, TÚ YA NO NECESITAS un bottonNavigation, tú debes optar por buscar otro componente, jamás en tu vida verás un BottonNav de más de 5 items.

FUENTE: DOCUMENTACIÓN DE ANDROID Y DOCUMENTACIÓN DE MATERIAL DESING.